# How can I exit a while loop after the user inputs "0"? If user inputs anything else, I want it to continue

Tags: python, while-loop

> Write a Python program that will ask the user for the name of a movie. Add the movie entered to a list. Continue asking for a movie until the user enters ‘0’.
> After all movies have been input, output the list of movies one movie per line.

This is what I've tried:

```py
def main():
    movies = []
    while movies != 0:
        movie = str(input("Enter the name of a movie: "))
        if movie == 0:
            break
        if movie != 0:
            movies.append(movie)

    print("That's your list")
    print(movies)

main()
```

Comment: `0` is not a string. Or a list. It is thus not practical to compare a string or a list to `0`.

Comment: [This is the Python tutorial from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Have a read.

Comment: `movie = str(input("Enter the name of a movie: "))` the `str` conversion is redundant. `input` always returns a str.

Comment: @Philipp Sure thing! I apologize if I made a typo (:

Comment: @00 Thank you very much for your help! I'll be happy to check it out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `break` keyword to interrupt either a `while` or a `for` loop.

The code given by BuddyBob is not 100% correct because it will include the "0" in the list of movies (since it is first appended).
The code given by ALI NAQI is actually comparing with a lowercase 'o'.

I believe this would be the best way:

```
def main():
    movies = []
    while True:
        movie = input("Enter the name of a movie: ")
        if movie == "0":
            break
        else:
            movies.append(movie)

    print("That's your list")
    print(movies)

main()
```

Comment: Where you used `true`, we've yet to cover that in class, but I'll definitely give it a shot and try and research the logic behind it. I'm not sure what it's actually saying, if that makes sense.

Though I tried it and it works haha, so I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: While True is a very literal expression. It means "keep doing this forever, until said otherwise". And that 'otherwise' happens when the the user introduces "0".

Comment: I wish I'd known that sooner. That'll help in a lot of my class work. Thank you very much for teaching me that! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> movie = str(input("Enter the name of a movie: "))
> if movie == 0:
>     break
> if movie != 0:
>     movies.append(movie)
> ```

The idea is correct here. But there is one mistake. You are asking for a string input then checking if the string input is an integer.
Try to take a string input but compare it to another string.

```
if movie == "0":
    break
```

**Suggested Code**
I changed your code your code up a bit too, much cleaner

```
def main():
   movies = []
   while "0" not in movies:
      movies.append(str(input("Enter the name of a movie: ")))
   print("That's your list")
   print(movies[:-1])
main()
```

Comment: That's a very simple way to fix things, and actually makes a lot of sense. I wasn't thinking when I assumed 0 would be read as a string too. Thank you very much for fixing it (:

Comment: Good to know, remember to check my answer so that people who have the same question no which answer helped the OP.

Comment: @BuddyBoblll Done!

Comment: Do you really want to have the string `"0"` in your list of movies?

Comment: Was thinking the same. Maybe we can just pop that out.

Comment: @matthias No, my instructor wants me to find a way to allow the user to return their list by simply typing "0." However, I tried the method given by Martí and it works too (:

Comment: This does not `output the list of movies one movie per line`.

Answer (score -1):

```py
 movie = str(input("Enter the name of a movie: "))
 if movie == 0:
     break
 if movie != 0:
     movies.append(movie)
```

This seems good but remember you are comparing string value (movie) with an integer like:

```py
if movie == 0:  #thats the mistake . now correct one is listed below

if movie == "o":
      break
```

Hope you understood this.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I must have assumed 0 would be read as a string too. I'm in an intro to programming course in college so I apologize if it looked very bad. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, neither do I understand how relying on Python's type handling is a *mistake*, nor do I understand why `movie` should be compared to a string consisting of one lower case o.